# Proper way to draw specific parts during onPaint event

Tags: winforms, compact-framework

When making **user control** what is the proper way to update specific part of a control?

Lets say i have Image property called CornerIcon and user sets a new image to this property. Do i need to have *onlyUpdateCornerIcon* as a flag to update that part only? OR just do onPaint without flag checks(without flag is expensive on devices that dont have enough memory and causes sluggish behavior on update)

While the flag seems okey to do its hard to keep track of things if the control is complicated one. For example if user changes height i will need to set the height changed flag and the *onlyUpdateCornerIcon* as they depend on each other to show the control correctly. As a control gets complicated i end up setting 5 or 6 flags for some props...any solution around this?

```
Image CornerIcon{
   get{return cornerIcon;}
   set{
     cornerIcon = value;
     onlyUpdateCornerIcon = true;
     Invalidate();
   }
}

onPaint(..){

   if(onlyUpdateCornerIcon){
     //updateImageHere
     return;
   }

   if(onlyUpdateText){
     //update Text here
     return;
   }

   //Paint all other props here
}
```

Comment: Or, you could just check whether `CornerIcon` is `null` or not...

Comment: This is already built-in, you can also use the Invalidate(Rectangle) overload.  And check it in your Paint event handler, the e.ClipRectangle property tells you what part of the window actually needs to be painted.  It does make code fairly brittle, bummer if you pass the wrong Rectangle, so not necessarily a good idea.  Optimize code only when it *needs* to be optimized.

Comment: checking null does not make sense for this question also its a cause of bug in this situation. @HansPassant any change in ClipRectangle(change in height/width) is handled by Control class - not worried about that. I am trying to find the best way to handle my custom props during paint.